# How do I get the full address of location using Google Places Autocomplete?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using `Google Places Autocomplete`. They start typing and when a user clicks on an address in the autocomplete list, I want this address to show in my `EditText`.

For example, when I click on `22 Moyclare Road, Dublin 13, Ireland` in the image below, I want `22 Moyclare Road, Dublin 13, Ireland` to show in my `Edittext`.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

But all I am getting is `Moyclare Road`, like this:

[image]

I am using the `getName` property of `place` like: `mEditInit.setText(place.getName());` but no matter what property I use I can't get it to display full address. Any ideas?

Here is the entire code of my `onActivityResult` function:

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);

        mEditInit.setText(place.getName());
      } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
        // Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // The user canceled the operation.
      }
      //  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `place.getAddress()` method instead of `place.getName()` to get the full address of a place.

```
mEditInit.setText(place.getAddress());
```

Make sure that you specify the address field, i.e. `Place.Field.ADDRESS`. Refer to Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details#place-details).

To get the full address for the Irish place you're searching for, instead of selecting `22 Moyclare Road, Dublin 13, Ireland`, select the Northside result from Autocomplete, i.e. `22 Moyclare Road, Northside, Dublin 13, Ireland`.

You'll get the following as output from `getAddress`:

```
22 Moyclare Rd, Northside, Dublin 13, D13 W2X2, Ireland
```

As for how to show this in the search bar, check out the accepted answer for related question [placeautocompletefragment full address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373630/placeautocompletefragment-full-address)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, set me on the right track. Now when I click on `22 Moyclare Road, Dublin 13, Ireland` from the autocomplete list, I get as output `Moyclare Rd, Northside, Dublin, Ireland`...which is closer than I was getting at first. But how can I get exactly as output what is listed in the autocomplete: `22 Moyclare Road, Dublin 13, Ireland` ?

Comment: You need to type the Northside address, i.e type "22 moyclare road northside" then select the first suggestion from Autocomplete.